# How to activate textbox depending on checkbox checked and get values from textbox using v-model in Vue js and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, checkbox

I am new to Vue js. I am trying to do an action form for the rest of API, but I am stuck at this point.

My action form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="required"> Social Media </label>
   <b-form-checkbox value="Facebook" v-model="selected"> FaceBook </b-form-checkbox>
   <b-form-checkbox value="Instagram" v-model="selected"> Instagram </b-form-checkbox>
   <b-form-checkbox value="Twitter" v-model="selected"> Twitter </b-form-checkbox>
   <b-form-checkbox v-on:click="onclick()" v-model="selected" > Other:</b-form-checkbox>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" :disabled='isDisabled'>
   <span class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></span>
</div>
```

My Vue instance

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {     
            selected: []     
        };
    }
```

My Output:

[image: Output]

Expected output when the checkbox of 'Other' is checked with an input value of 'Friends':

```
Selected: [ "Facebook", "Instagram", "Twitter", "Friends" ]
```

Comment: @Chistian add checkbox value `Friends` to `Other` Checkbox like `<b-form-checkbox value="Friends" v-model="selected"> Other:</b-form-checkbox>`

Comment: Thank you so much, but the values of the textbox should come from user , not just ‘friends’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      choices: ['Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Twitter'],
      selected: [],
      isDisabled: true,
      other: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onclick() {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled
      if(this.selected.length) {
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(s => s !== this.other)
      }
      this.other = ''
    },
    addType() {
      this.selected.push(this.other)
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="required"> Social Media </label>
   <li v-for="(item, i) in choices" :key="i">
     <input type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="selected" :id="item"> 
     <label :for="item">{{ item }}</label>
   </li>
   <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="onclick"  > 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" :disabled='isDisabled' v-model="other">
      <button v-show="!isDisabled" @click="addType">+</button>
   <span class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a value to the 'other' checkbox and only if this is selected, display the input field.

```
:disabled="!selected.includes('Other')"
```

Then add a second state variable and set it as v-model to the input.

```
 v-model="other"
```

You could also try to add the 'other'-String add the end of your 'selected' array but I think that would be much more confusing.

I've edited my codesandbox to get the wanted output by adding a computed value.

I made a codesandbox to show my solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-zhukovsky-id7vg?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks, but the output is not what I expected. The output should contain the values only.

Comment: The problem with your output is, that b-form-checkbox expects and returns an array of strings. But the input expects and returns a string. You can not use a single value for both of their v-models without doing some hacky stuff.

Comment: But I added a computed value to concat the values from the checkbox and the input field.